# Manage pubnub user permissions to soft delete messages with addMessageAction

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I want to implement the soft delete `addMessageAction` logic. Users should be allowed to add/remove actions only to their own messages. Admin users can add/remove actions for all the messages. Is there a way to check on PubNub's side that a user adds action to his own message? Checking it on the client doesn't sound secure enough.

```
pubnub.addMessageAction(
      {
        channel: 'ch-1'
        messageTimetoken: '15610547826970040',
        action: {
          type: 'deleted',
          value: '.',
        },
      },
      function(status, response) {
      }
   )
```

Comment: Currently, you can only grant permissions to "write" (publish messages and add messages to a channel). And grant permissions to "delete" messages (main and added messages). The best practice would be to use your own server or PubNub Functions to perform the delete message action on behalf of the users. In other words, grant the delete permission only to admins and have the admin (your server or PN Function) do the deletes on behalf of each user. Only allow the delete if the message being deleted is requested by the user that added it. There's more to this but that's the basics.

Comment: @CraigConover We can't revoke permissions to add message actions because of the same write permissions required to be able to send messages. I'm talking about adding delete action to a message, not delete operation which requires delete permissions.

Comment: Would you be willing to submit your issue to [PubNub Support}(https://support.pubnub.com)? Be sure to include a link to this post so that they can post the answer back here when it is resolved.